# What is the best data type for the field of format "YYYY-MM-DD" in oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g

I'm creating tables in Oracle 11g table and came across one date field of format "YYYY-MM-DD".
I don't want to use varchar2 for this and when I use number(5), it's still accepting the input. Then what's the meaning of limit 5 here?

Please suggest me the best datatype I can use here.

Comment: Best field is `date` and date does not have a format of it's own. What do you mean by "it's still accepting the input"? it can't

Answer (score 5):

This is, obviously, a **date** format mask. If you're about to store dates into that column, you should use the `DATE` datatype, such as

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (datum date);

Table created.
```

Don't use `VARCHAR2` (put strings into it, not dates) nor `NUMBER` (put numbers into it, not dates) datatypes for that. You'll regret it sooner than you think.

I'm going to enter some values into the table, showing different ways of how you could do that - it is important that you insert dates, not strings into it. Never rely on Oracle, implicitly converting strings you might provide to dates. Sooner or later, it'll produce an error.

```
SQL> insert into test values (date '2018-12-25');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values (to_date('09.05.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'));

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values (sysdate);

1 row created.
```

Now, several ways of selecting that value:

This one returns date in a format currently set by my database's NLS settings:

```
SQL> select * from test;

DATUM
--------
25.12.18
09.05.18
09.05.18
```

I'm forcing it to return values in desired format, using ALTER SESSION:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test;

DATUM
----------
2018-12-25
2018-05-09
2018-05-09
```

Yet another format; note that value inserted via the SYSDATE function (which returns DATE) contains date **and** time component. It was "invisible" in previous examples:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test;

DATUM
-------------------
25.12.2018 00:00:00
09.05.2018 00:00:00
09.05.2018 08:03:50
```

Using TO_CHAR function with some format (such as dd-mon-yyyy). I'm also requesting Oracle to "translate" month name into English (as my database works in Croatian):

```
SQL> select to_char(datum, 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english') datum from test;

DATUM
-----------
25-dec-2018
09-may-2018
09-may-2018

SQL>
```

**[EDIT]**

Oracle doesn't store DATE values in any "human" readable format (there's more to read on the Internet, Google for it). It is a format mask that represents that value to you.

I **strongly** suggest you **NOT** to store dates into any datatype column but DATE. It's a time bomb, waiting to explode (and then it'll hurt). Nobody stops you from entering a value as '1234-99-66' or '12-345-678'; what will you do with it, then?

Consider creating a view on a top of the table which uses TO_CHAR function and returns the value in a format you want ('yyyy-mm-dd'). DATE datatype column in a table makes sure that values are *valid*, and the view will let the third-party application to accept values it finds appropriate.

For example:

```
SQL> create view v_test as
  2    select to_char(datum, 'yyyy-mm-dd') datum
  3    from test;

View created.

SQL> select * from v_test;

DATUM
----------
2018-12-25
2018-05-09
2018-05-09

SQL>
```

So: you wouldn't let the third-party application to access the table, but the view instead.

Comment: Thank you @Littlefoot for providing more details. But I want to store the dates in yyyy-mm-dd format so that my third party tool access it in the same way and the third party doesn't support tricky ways to read. It just reads the value from DB blindly. Do we've any other way to store in the required format?

Comment: You cannot store a `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) value in any certain format, the values are stored in Oracle internal binary value. `yyyy-mm-dd` is just the **displayed** format. By setting `nls_date_format` you get desired output. You can set `nls_date_format` also by environment variable or in Windows Registry.

Comment: I've added some more text & examples into my message; have a look, please.